# Photoshop - Default Color Picker not shown

Tags: windows-7, adobe-photoshop

I am facing a problem with Photoshop in that it does not show the default color picker.

Please see the screenshot below. Can someone please help?

[image: 1]

Comment: Can you please explain in more details your issue in addition to just the screenshot? Looking at the screenshot it's not clear exactly what your issue is. Perhaps you could annotate the screenshot with some arrows or some identifying marking so that it's clearer?

Answer (score 1):

Open the `color picker` and select the `H box`.

That will bring your default color picker back.